# How to delete a whole element (index) out of a json dictionary on a certain condition

Tags: json, list, dictionary, nlp

Currently, I have a dictionary with legal decisions, looking like this (in total 391 decisions).

```
data = [{'text': "ECLI:NL:GHLEE:2002:AL8039   Instantie  Gerechtshof Leeuwarden  Datum uitspraak  18-10-2002  Datum publicatie  08-10-2003  Zaaknummer   BK 866/98 Vennootschapsbelasting   Rechtsgebieden   Belastingrecht   Bijzondere kenmerken"},
{'text': "ECLI:NL:GHARL:2014:5893   Instantie  Gerechtshof Arnhem-Leeuwarden  Datum uitspraak  15-07-2014  Datum publicatie  01-08-2014  Zaaknummer   14/00030   Formele relaties  Eerste aanleg: ECLI:NL:RBGEL:2013:4925 , Bekrachtiging/bevestiging   Rechtsgebieden   Belastingrecht   Bijzondere kenmerken"},
{'text': "ECLI:NL:GHARL:2015:7518   Instantie  Gerechtshof Arnhem-Leeuwarden  Datum uitspraak  06-10-2015  Datum publicatie  16-10-2015  Zaaknummer   14/01259   Formele relaties  Eerste aanleg: ECLI:NL:RBGEL:2014:6894 , Bekrachtiging/bevestiging Cassatie: ECLI:NL:HR:2016:2736    **Rechtsgebieden   Strafrecht** Bijzondere kenmerken"}]
```

In this project I want to delete the elements where there is "Rechtsgebieden   Strafrecht" in the string. Therefore, I have to loop over all the elements, and then delete the whole index number

```
{'text': "ECLI:NL:GHARL:2015:7518   Instantie  Gerechtshof Arnhem-Leeuwarden  Datum uitspraak  06-10-2015  Datum publicatie  16-10-2015  Zaaknummer   14/01259   Formele relaties  Eerste aanleg: ECLI:NL:RBGEL:2014:6894 , Bekrachtiging/bevestiging Cassatie: ECLI:NL:HR:2016:2736    **Rechtsgebieden   Strafrecht** Bijzondere kenmerken"}
```

I thought of something like this, but I can't seem to find a solution to get the right index number (as data[d] does not work of course):

```
    substring = "Rechtsgebieden   Strafrecht"
    for d in data:
        if substring in str(d):
            del data[d]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see following points:

1. You should use `d['text']` and not `str(d)` for your testing.
2. You should not modify your `data` while you are iterating on that. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it) for more details on why.

See this example of incorrect behavior

```
>>> data
[{'text': 'some text'}, {'text': 'text with value to be removed'}, {'text': 'text with value to be removed BUT WILL NOT BE REMOVED'}, {'text': 'some other text'}, {'text': 'this text is also fine'}]
>>> VALUE_TO_REMOVE
'value to be removed'
>>> for i, item in enumerate(data):
...     if VALUE_TO_REMOVE in item['text']:
...             del data[i]
... 
>>> data
[{'text': 'some text'}, {'text': 'text with value to be removed BUT WILL NOT BE REMOVED'}, {'text': 'some other text'}, {'text': 'this text is also fine'}]
>>>
```

3. Since you can not remove the entry from data during iteration, create a new data list where each dictionary satisfy your condition.

Preferred correct manner:

```
>>> data
[{'text': 'some text'}, {'text': 'text with value to be removed'}, {'text': 'text with value to be removed BUT WILL NOT BE REMOVED'}, {'text': 'some other text'}, {'text': 'this text is also fine'}]
>>> VALUE_TO_REMOVE
'value to be removed'
>>> new_data = [x for x in data if VALUE_TO_REMOVE not in x['text']]
>>> new_data
[{'text': 'some text'}, {'text': 'some other text'}, {'text': 'this text is also fine'}]
>>>
```

4. In case, you data is huge and you do not want to make a copy, you can mark the individual dictionaries with key 'Do not use' and make use of that later while processing. See below:

```
>>> data
[{'text': 'some text'}, {'text': 'text with value to be removed'}, {'text': 'text with value to be removed BUT WILL NOT BE REMOVED'}, {'text': 'some other text'}, {'text': 'this text is also fine'}]
>>> for item in data:
...     if VALUE_TO_REMOVE in item['text']:
...             item['DO NOT USE'] = True
... 
>>> data
[{'text': 'some text'}, {'text': 'text with value to be removed', 'DO NOT USE': True}, {'text': 'text with value to be removed BUT WILL NOT BE REMOVED', 'DO NOT USE': True}, {'text': 'some other text'}, {'text': 'this text is also fine'}]
>>>
```